# Client ssl using mbedtls using C

Tags: mbedtls

I am getting error message during handshake

- `mbedtls_ssl_read_record_layer()` returned `-29184 (-0x7200)`
- `mbedtls_ssl_read_record()` returned `-29184 (-0x7200)`

Why this error..?

Answer (score 0):

You can look up Mbed TLS error codes with the `strerror` utility available with the library's source code.

```
programs/util/strerror 29184 
Last error was: -0x7200 - SSL - An invalid SSL record was received
```

There could be many reasons for receiving an invalid record. If this is on the first message received from a server, this probably indicates that the server isn't using the TLS protocol. At other times, it probably indicates that something is corrupting packets. This could also indicate that the peer is using some TLS protocol extension that your library doesn't support, although this would usually be detected during the handshake. With DTLS, it could be a stray packet remaining from a previous connection on the same ports.